# MySQL on Docker remote access

Tags: mysql, docker, remote-access, iptables

In my docker instance, there is an image **mysql/mysql-server:latest** which I've run it by:

```
# docker run - name=mysql1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -p 3306:3306 -d <Image-ID>
```

Also I run the following:

```
# docker logs mysql1 | grep GENERATED
```

to obtain **root** password. Then I run:`# docker exec -it mysql1 mysql -uroot -p`
Then:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
```

Besides I open port **3306** in **iptables**:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp - dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp - dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

But I'm not able to access MySQL remotely. Obviously when I run the following from ***another machine***:

```
> mysql -uroot -p -h 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

I see the following error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.xxx.xxx' (10060 "Unknown error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to disallow remote root login, I imagine this Docker image has followed that.

You can do one of two things:

1. Allow remote logins as root (not ideal)

   USE mysql;

   UPDATE user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';
2. Create another user with the appropriate permissions.. (Preferred option)